# apache subprocess can't access files

Tags: apache, centos

i'm running into a problem where a program written to be accessed as a web service can't access anything in the local file system. running the program from the command line works correctly, but fails when called via apache as a subprocess exec'd via `system()` from a php script ; it simply can't find the files it's supposed to work on. i'm convinced this is an apache configuration issue, as the program has no problem reading /var/www/html [the webserver document root] and any/all files/directories under it.

here are some details :

- virtual centos 7 server running apache 2.4.6.
- the program runs as user apache
- it can read / [root dir] and interprets it correctly [i.e. it really is / the system root, not /var/www/html]
- it doesn't have access to /tmp at all, nor to /var/tmp
- some external files are network mounted on /mnt. the program can access /mnt, but attempts to read /mnt/*{anything}* fail -- even though remote shares are mounted w/effective uid/gid as apache and all files/directories are readable by world.
- selinux is currently disabled
- for kicks, i tried setting `Require all granted` inside `<Directory / >` and `<Directory /tmp >` in `httpd.conf`, but that didn't change anything.

does anyone have any idea what could be causing this and how i could fix it ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if selinux is restricting access?

You can see if Selinux is causing issues by install selinux troubleshooting

yum install -y setroubleshoot
sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log

Comment: Rather than this being an answer, this should be a comment instead as it's probing for information.

Comment: thanks, @r-chan, i'll give that a try and let you know how it goes.